# Upgrade Issues .Net 6

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, upgrade, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

1. IsMimeMultipartContent()
2. IAuthenticationFilter is not available
3. Read Multipart
4. HttpContextWrapper

I am expecting to identify how can I achieve these when I am upgrading the FW4.8 to .Net6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "CS1061: ActionExecutingContext does not contain a definition for
> Request".

`HttpContentMultipartExtensions.IsMimeMultipartContent` is used to determine whether the specified content is MIME multipart content.

In Asp.Net Core, you can check that the request is multipart/form-data using property [HttpRequest.HasFormContentType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.hasformcontenttype?view=aspnetcore-6.0):

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
{
    if (!actionContext.HttpContext.Request.HasFormContentType){}
}
```

You can also refer to [Mathieu Renda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45871889/18789859).

> IAuthenticationFilter is not available.

Asp.net core doesn't contain the `IAuthenticationFilter`, if you want to authenticated the user, you can refer to [Brando Zhang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72484351/18789859).

> Error: HttpRequest does not contain a definition for Content

You can take a look at this official document: [Upload files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

And you can also refer to these two posts to solve your problem: [ReadAsMultipartAsync equvialent in .NET core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50368897/readasmultipartasync-equvialent-in-net-core-2), [MultipartFormDataStreamProvider for ASP.NET Core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866849/multipartformdatastreamprovider-for-asp-net-core-2).

> Replacement for HttpContextWrapper

The HttpContextWrapper class derives from the HttpContextBase class and serves as a wrapper for the HttpContext class. So I think it is possible to access HttpContext directly in Asp.Net Core: [Access HttpContext in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Hope this can help you.